# Unable to give button element focus

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to give focus to the following button in my Angular 2 application:

```
<button (click)="confirmOk(modalId)" class="btn btn-default ok" id="ok-button" tabindex="0">
    <img src="/assets/shared/images/icon-ok.png" />
    {{okText}}
</button>
```

On the page, I open the developer console (F12) and type the following:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ok-button");
```

At this point, it returns the element I'm expecting, so I know JavaScript is finding the button.  So then I go back into the console and type:

```
e.focus();
```

... and the button doesn't get focus.  I know it's not getting focus because I have a CSS class for this button's :focus state that should put a big red border around the button if it receives focus.  And I can indeed see that red button when I manually click on the button to give it focus.

Following the suggestions in the comments, I also tried adding this code to the event which triggers the button to appear on the page:

```
showButton();  // the button is triggered to appear here
setTimeout(function() {
   let e = document.getElementById('ok-button');
   if (e) {
       e.focus();  // breakpoint here does indeed get triggered
   }
}, 2000)
```

Unfortunately, that also didn't work.

**Update:** this may be helpful.  When I click Refresh on the browser, the target button momentarily receives focus before the page actually refreshes.  So my guess is it's something to do with the timing on the page, or maybe Angular's repainting of the page?

Comment: What event are you binding the `focus()` method on? In other words, is there a button to be pushed or does this happen while loading the page? If you are just arbitrary calling `focus()` then maybe wrap it in a function.

Comment: i guess behaviours can differ here, when i tested in firefox and chrome, my button wasn't focused when typing from the console. However, in a `ready` function, it worked in chrome, and not on firefox..

Comment: You're focusing on the console, not the window. try setting a timeout of 2 seconds or so to focus the button

Comment: wrapping in a function, setting a timeout, and executing the focus() from code rather than console didn't work

Comment: do you want the real focus to be on the button (to be able to press "Enter" for example) or just a visual effect? If the latter, the style can be set via a class (and "Enter" could be emulated with a `keyup` event)

Comment: Where is your focus, when it's not getting applied to the button?

Comment: @Kaddath Ideally I'd like it to be real focus so i don't need to code custom Enter and Tab functions.  But if that's what it takes, then I guess I don't have a choice.

Comment: @freginold I can't tell for sure, but I think it's on the button that triggered this button to appear.

Comment: Update: this may be helpful.  When I click Refresh on the browser, the target button momentarily receives focus before the page actually refreshes.  So my guess is it's something to do with the timing on the page, or maybe Angular's repainting of the page?  I'll update the post with this info.

Comment: ok, I got it... apparently it was because I simply had the console open even though I wasn't typing in it!  The code above works when the console is not open.  Amazing. @ThumChoonTat do you want to type up the answer, and I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simply that the console was open while I was trying to get focus.  Even if I didn't type in the console, it was constantly somehow stealing focus.  Once I closed the console, and I tried to get focus from code rather from the browser, the focus was successfully applied.